# Adding Gmap to webforms

Tags: 7, webforms, google-maps

I allready download gmap, location and some other modules that in this catagory and still I dont succeed to add a field in gmap type to my webform page so users could put it their location (not in the register of the users, in the form that I build!

How do I do it? I saw this:
https://drupal.org/project/webform_gmap
but it's for Drupal 6 and I'm using 7.

Comment: Well, you have a working example for Drupal 6. Follow these directions are create a version for Drupal 7 https://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#detailed_change_instructions, get involved in the Drupal community!

Comment: It sounds like you haven't finished configuring it and adding it as a field:
https://drupal.org/node/1038034

Comment: I dont find that option that I configure it as a field.. can you direct me please? because I think I did excatly as this article. in addition to that I watched some videos that configure it and I did exactly as they did and still it doesnt work in my drupal site.

Comment: in some videos I saw that when I configure it a new tab should displayied to me in the content type that I added it, the "locative information" tab, and its not exsist to me.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7: Webform Gmap Location

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/drecksau/2096563

> This module adds «Gmap» component to Webform.
>   This component allows you to mark the location using the Google map.
>   Also below the map can be displayed autocomplete address field.